# Is it possible to surface an Azure AppInsights dashboard in the Azure DevOps Server 2019 (on prem)?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-application-insights

We have some telemetry in a certain App Insights bucket in Azure. We present it as a dashboard there. However, being in Azure it is not visible to the teams in an obvious way.

We use Azure DevOps Server 2019 (on prem). Is it possible to surface App Insights data in Azure DevOps Server 2019 in a form of an Azure DevOps dashboard?

**EDIT 1**

Showing just the `metrics` chart is not sufficient for us. Our dashboards are based on Kusto queries into `customEvents`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but not straight forward, you might need to use the APIs(both Azure Devops API and App Insights API) to get the data from AppInsights and then create those widgets.

[`AppInsights API`](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/)

[`Create Widget API`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-dashboard-widget?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the [“Azure Application Insights Widgets” extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-appinsights.ApplicationInsightsWidgets) in Azure Devops Server.

This extension contains two widgets: **“Azure Application Insights Chart Widget “** and **“App Insights” Widget**.

These two widgets can call **‘Metrics’** in APP insights.

Then they can use these information to generate graphs or display the obtained data.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This will not work for us, we are looking to run custom kusto queries from insights to recreate the dashboard in Azure devops. Please, see **EDIT 1**.

Comment: According to your requirement, I find an existing extension: [Insights Lab Application Insights Analytics Widget](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=InsightsLab.aiaWidget&ssr=false#overview). But during my testing, I can't use this widget: 404 error.If you have the same issue, you can try Sajeetharan's suggestion. I do not have much experience with AppInsights API , but you could refer to this [App Insights Events Widget source code](https://github.com/kshyju/VSTS-AppInsights).

Comment: Sajeetharan's suggestion is not very helpful, because it lacks details.

Comment: Since there is no existing widget to meet your needs, you may refer to Sajeetharan's suggestion. Then you can modify it based on [this extension source code](https://github.com/kshyju/VSTS-AppInsights). This source code may contain some details.Sorry not much experience about AppInsights API.